# Proxying Minecraft through a SSH tunnel

Tags: ssh, tunnel, minecraft

My setup is this:

- My computer has a Minecraft server running on it, listening to port 25565. It is protected by a firewall, so can not be accessed externally (and I have no control over port forwarding)
- I have a server that *is* publicly accessible.

I want to make it so that the server forwards all requests on port 25565 to my computer, via an (ssh) tunnel.

I tried using ssh command on my computer to create a reverse tunnel, however that doesn't seem to work:

```
ssh -R 25565:localhost:25565 user@myserver
```

Answer (score 0):

You must enable **GatewayPorts** in the server sshd config in order for remote port forwarding to work. Depending on what it's set to you may need to specify the bind address when using the `-R` option, otherwise the tunnel will only accept connections from localhost. e.g `ssh -R *:25565:localhost:25565 user@myserver`.